# Passing structs into a method and making assingments with scanf_S

Tags: c, pointers, struct, scanf

I am brand new to C and have begun a small project to practice and refine some basics.

Right now, I am having trouble assigning the name variable in stuct player. Specifically, I want to do this by passing the player struct into the method titleScreen and make the assignment there.
I want to do this with scanf, but nothing seems to work and I have hit a wall.

Is there something wrong with the way I have passed the pointer?

Please help

Thanks

```
typedef struct player { 
    char name[20];
    int health;
} player;

void titleScreen(player *u) {
    printf("Press Enter: \n");
    scanf_s("Press Enter");
    printf("                                                |>>>\r\n"
         "                                                |\r\n"
         "                                            _  _|_  _\r\n"
         "                                           |;|_|;|_|;|\r\n"
         "                                           \\\\.    .  /\r\n"
         "                                            \\\\:  .  /\r\n"
         "                                             ||:   |\r\n"
         "                                             ||:.  |\r\n"
         "                                             ||:  .|\r\n"
         "                                             ||:   |       \\,/\r\n"
         "                                             ||: , |            /`\\\r\n"
         "                                             ||:   |\r\n"
         "                                             ||: . |\r\n"
         "              __                            _||_   |\r\n"
         "     ____--`~    '--~~__            __ ----~    ~`---,              ___\r\n"
         "-~--~                   ~---__ ,--~'                  ~~----_____-~'   `~----~~");
    printf("Name your hero: ");
    scanf_s(" %s", u->name); //Error occurs here
    
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    player user;  //The User
    player *uPtr; //Pointer to user
    uPtr = &user;
    user.health = 100;

    titleScreen(uPtr);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: If you're new to C, I suggest forgetting those `foo_s()` functions exist and don't use them. All they're good for is locking you into Microsoft's environment (and the MSVC implementation doesn't even follow the annex to the standard that was made to pander to them, making it doubly annoying!)

Comment: I'd also suggest not using `scanf()` or `fscanf()`... too error prone and too hard to recover from input issues with. `fgets()` is your friend, followed by other parsing if needed (which might include `sscanf()`)

Comment: Thanks Shawn, 
I had no idea there were so many hahaha. I'm doing a course with my University for C and they suggested I use scanf(), but I'm completly open to finding a more efficient shortcut.

Comment: It works for me if I use the normal standard (non _s) versions of scanf.  https://onlinegdb.com/VuIX5hQ9z  The otherthing I would mention is that you don't need toi use "\r\n" at the end of the strings.  If you use "\n" the text will be printed with a carriage return and line feed both when you compile on Windows and just a linefeed when you compile it on Linux - the standard library does the right thing for you if you just use "\n".

Comment: Well in that case I'm glad I was on the right track. That has completly answered my question, but I don't know how to use scanf without the safe function. Visual Studio gives me the following error if I try to incorporate it:
'scanf': This function or variable may be unsafe. Consider using scanf_s instead. To disable deprecation, use _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS.
What is CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS?

Comment: Found the solution, a quick google search told me to include 
#pragma warning(disable : 4996). This Allows normal functions to be used.
Is it safe or practical to include this at the start of every program?

Comment: @Rrunr I would use a different compiler, like gcc or clang